# Why didn't I get any content between HTML tag?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract data from this website "https://www.physiotherapyexercises.com/". But when i run the following code i get only the html body , didn't get the content between the HTMl tags.

```
import requests
import bs4

url = "https://www.physiotherapyexercises.com/"
res = requests.get(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')

print(soup)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post expected output. What information you are searching for?

Comment: i want to extract the all exercise from this website. For this i have to load the content first . when i get the sourch file of this website there was no content . thats why i am asking for the way to load all the content in soup variable

Comment: When I run your code you posted, the soup is printed on screen normally. Maybe some part of content is loaded dynamically by JavaScript and BeautifulSoup doesn't see it.

Comment: i want to extract the all exercise data(sidemanu "Information -> Full details of all exercises ")  from this website. but when i select the class of the div i get nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you are searching for is loaded from other location using Javascript. You can use `requests`/`re`/`json` modules to obtain the information.

For example:

```
import re
import json
import requests

url = 'https://www.physiotherapyexercises.com/Js/Data/ExerciseData_English_2019_12_06_00_49_56.js'

data = json.loads(re.search(r'exerciseRecords=(.*?]);', requests.get(url).text).group(1))

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for exercise in data:
    print(*exercise['Texts'], sep='\n')
    print('-' * 80)
```

Prints:

```
...

Strength - knee - flexors - wall mounted pulleys - prone.
Knee flexor strengthening in prone using pulleys
To strengthen the knee flexors.
To strengthen the muscles at the back of your thigh.
Position the patient in prone facing away from the pulleys. Adjust the pulley system so that the direction of pull opposes knee flexion. Instruct the patient to flex their knee.
Position yourself lying on your stomach. Adjust the pulley system so that the direction of pull is towards the top of the bed. Start with your knee straight and leg resting on the bed. Finish with your knee bent.
More advanced: 1. Progress using strength training principles.

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Strength - knee - flexors - theraband - prone.
Knee flexor strengthening in prone using theraband
To strengthen the knee flexors.
To strengthen the muscles at the back of your thigh.
Position the patient in prone with their knee extended. Adjust the theraband so that the direction of pull opposes knee flexion. Instruct the patient to flex their knee.
Position yourself lying on your stomach. Adjust the theraband so that the direction of pull is towards the top of the bed. Start with your knee straight and leg resting on the bed. Finish with your knee bent.
Less advanced: 1. Downgrade the colour of the theraband. More advanced: 1. Upgrade the colour of the theraband.

... and so on.
```